# pass username, pwd, server information in expect shell scripting

Tags: bash, shell

I want to pass all the remote server names as shell script arguments and then want my script to copy the given file/directory to all remote servers. Below is my code.

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/expect <<EOD

#connect via scp

usr=Joe
pwd=Password
file_location=/home/file1.txt

for a in $@
do
  spawn scp -r $file_location  "$usr@$a:$file_location"

expect -nocase "password: "

send "$pwd\r"

expect eof
EOD
```

Username and password is same for all the remote servers. So I am hard-coding them for time being but while running the script I see a problem with that..

```
>./scp1.sh server1 server2
invalid command name "usr=Joe"
while executing
"usr=Joe"
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: why isn't this just an expect script? bash isn't even doing anything here.

Comment: How can I read the command line arguments in Expect?

Answer (score 1):

To read command line arguments from [expect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect):

```
$argc - number items of arguments passed to a script.
$argv - list of the arguments.
$argv0 - name of the script.
```

This was take from [this site](http://www.fundza.com/tcl/script_shell/arguments.html)

If you want more help with `expect` then google about `tcl` because `expect` is an extension to `tcl` language

Comment: Initially I tried with single server and that was easy as I hard-coded it. So I thought of reading the command line arguments and pass them by running scp command in a for loop. But looks like I cannot use my regular shell scripting here. Need to do some more research on expect. Anyways thank you for the reply. I will read about tcl and try it again.